# How to calculate a hash like SHA1 on a school calculator?

Tags: math, hash, calculator, md5, sha

**Is it possible to calculate a hash (like SHA-1, SHA-256 or MD5) on a "normal" school calculator?**

If I could not generate this hash, could calculate it with some math a hash self on the calculator?

*(I using in school a "TI-30X Plus", cost 20$ or so...)*
(sry for my bad english)

Comment: yes if you have enough memory or paper (and time)

Comment: you need a programable calculator with bit operations ... doing this manually is not reliable as it is a lot of operations per each BYTE.... If you have small PC instead you can use Total Commander for this ... just to be more clear I got a C++ implementation of CRC32,SHA-1,MD5 in single file and it is 27807 Bytes of code. btw From those only CRC32 might be computed easily on calculator as its division of polynomials but you didi not ask about that one ...